# Failed: Invalid provider for the NgModule 'DynamicTestModule' - only instances of Provider and Type are allowed, got: [[object Object]?]

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, karma-jasmine, jasmine-node, jasmine2.0

So there's this delightful error that's the very definition of annoying

this is the describe method:

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [ MapMap ],
  imports: [IonicStorageModule.forRoot()],
  providers: [PopoverController, AngularDelegate, UrlSerializer, File]
  }).compileComponents();
```

First it had no providers, but then complained that it needed those providers. After I added those providers it produced the error

"Failed: Invalid provider for the NgModule 'DynamicTestModule' - only instances of Provider and Type are allowed, got: [..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ?[object Object]?]
"

I tried looking for answers but cannot find anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add "ngx" to the end of "import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';
"